# GDAL 2.4 but the current library version is 2.2

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate

After upgrading to gdal 2.4 on Debian testing (buster), I get

```
$ gdal_translate
ERROR 1: gdal_translate was compiled against GDAL 2.4, but the current
library version is 2.2
```

I've checked with synaptic and libgdal20 is 2.4

Any clue on what to do?

Comment: Stock debian repositories? Is "which gdal_translate" giving you /usr/bin/... or something else?

Comment: Yes, which gdal_translate gives /usr/bin/gdal_translate

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error any more. Some other upgraded package must have made the change, sorry cannot be more precise.

Comment: Great it works now, that's more important :) I'd suggest you vote to close your question as not reproducable anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I answer to sort of close the question)
I cannot reproduce the error any more. Some other upgraded package must have made the change, sorry cannot be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu, a simpler solution to install the latest gdal for python3: install library files via libgdal-dev, and python wrapper via python-gdal

sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-gdal
for python2:

sudo apt-get install python-gdal